# How to create a Micronaut project with JPA Entity from external classes from another jar

Tags: micronaut-data, micronaut-rest

1. I have a Micronaut project, and I'm trying to build the project with my external Entity classes which are in Spring JPA added on dependency in pom.xml, but I'm always having an error: **Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Entities not found for JPA configuration: 'default' within packages [packageName]**

- [Failed] I have already added my Entity jar a dependency with "scope compile" in pom.xml
- [Failed] Already created a class file with "@Introspected(classes = User.class)", the User.class resides in my external Entity jar, as per micronaut documentation we can use the already compile classes by adding the annonation @Introspected, but this doesn't work
- [Failed] I also combine the @Entity and @Introspected at the same class if this can determine the Entity class, but it doesn't work
- [Failed] I also tried to create an AnnotationMapper, this will automate the mapping of package with "javax.persistence.Entity", see a reference https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/3.5.x/inject/src/main/java/io/micronaut/inject/beans/visitor/EntityReflectiveAccessAnnotationMapper.java
- removing dependency micronaut-data-spring-jpa doesn't requires me an Entity class, but the auto migration of Micronaut to Spring JPA repository will be having an error.

Note: In my Micronaut project, I don't have @Entity classes, since I want to use the external jar of Spring JPA Entity classes that I made so I can reuse it to other applications.

Edit: mvn clean install or run as log:

> io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException:
> Bean definition [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [org.hibernate.boot.SessionFactoryBuilder]

Message: Entities not found for JPA configuration: 'default' within packages [packageName]. Check that you have correctly specified a package containing JPA entities within the "jpa.default.entity-scan.packages" property in your application configuration and that those entities are either compiled with Micronaut or a build time index produced with @Introspected(packages="foo.bar", includedAnnotations=Entity.class) declared on your Application class
Path Taken: SessionFactory.hibernateSessionFactory(SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder) --> SessionFactory.hibernateSessionFactory([SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder]) --> SessionFactoryBuilder.hibernateSessionFactoryBuilder([MetadataSources metadataSources],ValidatorFactory validatorFactory,Interceptor hibernateInterceptor)

Comment: Do you have the annotation processor properly set up? Do you see extra classes being generated?

Comment: @Denis, can you further elaborate?

if I maven clean install, I'm also encountering it aside from running the application, see logs above (can't paste in comment the logs, it is too long)

Comment: The problem might be that you don't have properly set up `io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java` at the annotation processor classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did to resolve my own issue:

1. I started from scratch again, and I use the https://micronaut.io/launch/
   to generate the workspace (its like https://start.spring.io/, for spring)
2. Instead of directly using my User.class from external jar, I create it first on micronaut project, (including repository), and prove that application starts and works (I expose also a service to trigger for testing)
3. Then, I change the reference of User.class, from local to external jar. When I initially try it, without "@Introspected", "No persistent classes found" was encountered, but with "@Introspected", it works.
4. I able to use the entity from my external class, but not the repository class (for now, will not pursue further research how to use external jpa repository class to micronaut)

Comment: An external project with repositories would need to have `micronaut-data` annotation processor for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

- Adding `@Introspected(classes={Entity}.class)` on your **Application.java** class of your *Micronaut Proj*

> ```
> @Introspected(classes = {Entity}.class)
> public class Application {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         Micronaut.run(Application.class, args);
>     }
> }
> ```

This will import your entity class and make *JPA* to recognise it as a *JPA Entity*.

**Just a reminder:** You must have your {Entity} class annotated with `@Entity` from

> `import javax.persistence.Entity;`